# Use the definition of derivative to find $f'(x)$ for $f(x) = x^{1/2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, radicals

This is an analysis question so we use the definition that the derivative of a function is, $$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$ But I'm not really sure if I should just continue to say that $x=c$ for now as the second $x$ perhaps as if $f(x) = \sqrt c$. Obviously if we leave $x$ as is, $(f(x)-f(x)) = 0$ and the lim is $0$, but this is obviously not the case since $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{ f(x)-f(c) }{ x-c }= \frac{\sqrt x - \sqrt c}{x-c}$$

and remark that: $$x-c=(\sqrt x - \sqrt c)(\sqrt x + \sqrt c)$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $x$ as $c+h$, so you have
$$\begin{align}
 f'(c)&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{c+h}-\sqrt{c}}{h}  \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{c+h-c}{(\sqrt{c+h}+\sqrt c)h} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt c}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is the calculus definition

Comment: They're literally the same thing.