# Find the derivative of $y = x^{1/2}$ by using differentiation from first principle.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For this question, I tried to apply the derivative limit formula on it but I have a problem with the square root there:
$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+\Delta x}-\sqrt x}{\Delta x}$$
If I divide each term by $\Delta x$, as $\Delta x \to 0$，I get $1$ but this is not the correct answer.

I have also tried to expand $(x + \Delta x)^{1/2}$ by using binomial expansion but I forgot the ways to  apply it on the power of $1/2$.

Anyone know how to solve it by using differentiation from first principle?

Comment: By "from first principle," do you mean using the limit definition?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561732/use-the-definition-of-derivative-to-find-fx-for-fx-x1-2

Comment: I mean the differentiation which defined by dy/dx = when the delta x approaches to zero {((f(x+delta x)-f(x))/ delta x}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to figure out the following:
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac {\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}{h}$$

Rewrite the denominator as $h=(x+h)-x$:
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac {\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}{(x+h)-x}$$

Rewrite the denominator as $(x+h)-x=(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x)$:
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac {\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}{(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x)}$$

Simplify the fraction:
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac {1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x}$$

The numerator now has nothing to do with $h$, so rewrite the limit as simply the numerator over the limit of the denominator as $h$ approaches $0$
$$\frac {1}{\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x}$$

The limit as $h$ approaches $0$ of $\sqrt{x+h}$ is $\sqrt x$, so adding $\sqrt x$ to that makes it $2\sqrt x$:
$$\frac {1}{2\sqrt x}$$

Thus, we have gotten rid of the limit and are now done!